# How to make the cubes to get close to each other and then back to opposite direction and then back close nonstop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Like a gate that opens and closes all the time.
I'm using two cubes as gateParts and moving them each one towards the other but even if I'm checking the distance they never stop at 0.1f distance or less they get inside each other and then stop.

Then I want when they are at distance 0.1 or when the "Gate" is close to moving the cubes back so the "Gate" will get open.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] gateParts;
    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(gateParts[0].position, gateParts[1].position);

        if (dist > 0.1f)
        {
            gateParts[0].position = Vector3.MoveTowards(gateParts[0].position, gateParts[1].position
                , Time.deltaTime * speed);

            gateParts[1].position = Vector3.MoveTowards(gateParts[1].position, gateParts[0].position
                , Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this by script, I would suggest making an animation of this behavior. Then, check off looping for the animation, and then it'll do this non-stop motion you want.